# javascript - Highcharts - Type Bar - How to set different starting for each bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, highcharts

I have bar chart, in which I want each bar to start different value. Now they all starts from 0. I have only find how to change the starting point, that would be the same for each. Like all staring from 1.

But I need the First to be draw like 1-2, Second: 1-4 and Third: 7-10.
How can I vary it for different cases?

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        renderTo: 'container'
 },
 xAxis: {
        categories: ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
 },
 series: [{
        data: [{
            name: 'Point 1',
            y: 2
        }, {
            name: 'Point 2',
            y: 4
        }, {
            name: 'Point 3',
            y: 10
        }]
 }]
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `columnrange` chart type is for:

- http://www.highcharts.com/demo/columnrange

Use the `inverted` property in order to make it a bar instead of a column:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted)

Example:

```
    chart: {
        type: 'columnrange',
        inverted: true
    }
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/columnrange/

Comment: Thanks, that looks like, what I have been looking for. How can build some foreach-loop, cause I should read and represent table information, where Y-axis is fixed 0-24 and X-axis is read from table? If possible, each X-axis item, will have 4 different colums (in different rows). Like Jan: 1-5, 2-7

Comment: I think you'll need to start a new question for that issue, and include the data that you need to loop through, and an example of your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

the possible solution is to make your bar chart 'stacking' and add new data array to your series where offsets will be set and then make them "invisible":

```
plotOptions: {
   series: {
     stacking: 'normal'
   }
},
series: [{
    data: [{name: 'Point 1', y: 2}, 
           {name: 'Point 2', y: 4}, 
           {name: 'Point 3', y: 10}]
    },{
    data: [{name: 'Point 1', y: 2}, 
           {name: 'Point 2', y: 4}, 
           {name: 'Point 3', y: 10}], 
    color: 'white',
    enableMouseTracking:false,
    showInLegend: false
}]
```

I hope [this example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwOAxx) will explain it better

Comment: I have now managed to set two tables for the chart data: var people = ['People1', '', '', '', 'People2', '', '', '''];  

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
 chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  renderTo: 'reservationChart'
  },
 xAxis: {
  categories: people,
  title: {
   text: 'Name,    align: "high",
     rotation: 0
   }
  },
 yAxis: {
  categories: [00, 02, 04, 06, 08, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24],
  title: {
   text: 'Reservation'
   }
  },
 plotOptions: {
  series: {
   stacking: 'normal'
  }
 },
 series: dataset
   });
 });

Comment: Damn.... So basicly I have now two tables, people for Xaxis and dataset for Yaxis, and now I should populate those tables from my model. How can I do that? I have ascx-file for my view.